# How to find string in file in Osx terminal?

Tags: bash, grep

I am just getting my head around using Osx terminal and trying to find a word fe 'debugger' inside a file with .js extension in any subdirectory. How can I just return .js files and show the linenumber?:

```
  grep -lr debugger /directoryname
```

Comment: `find /dirname -type f -name '*.js' -exec grep -H debugger '{}' +`.

Comment: that looks good and is it possible to show the line number?

Comment: Yes, add whatever option you like, including `--color`: `find /directoryname -type f -name '*.js' -exec grep -Hn --color debugger '{}' +`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find /dirname -name "*.js" | xargs grep -n debugger
```

or

```
grep -r -n --include \*.js debugger
```

Comment: This is not safe at all. Use `find`'s builtin `xargs` capability, i.e., `-exec {} +`, or at least use the `find -print0 | xargs -0` idiom.

Comment: @4ae1e1: can you point me to some documentation as to why this is unsafe? I've never heard that...

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk:_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-